# Python: Unable to extract whole columns from csv file

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried to extract some columns from a csv file, but the result printed out shows only 0 or 1, not the real values from the columns.

With some great help from stackoverflow users, now I have no error message on my code to extract columns.

csv file example data:

```
companyID,year,company_age,Debt_TA,gcp
654001,2000,49,0.14,0
654001,2001,50,0.17,0
654001,2002,51,0.23,1
112089,2013,38,0.11,0
112089,2014,39,0.13,0
342980,2007,54,0.15,0
342980,2008,55,0.22,1
113456,2009,12,0.11,0
113456,2010,13,0.13,0
```

code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from sklearn import feature_extraction
#from sklearn.svm import SVC
#from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
#from sklearn import model_selection


def parseFile (filename):
    companies = list ()
    with open (filename) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader (csvfile, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"')       
        for index, line in enumerate (reader):
            #print index, line
            if (index > 0 and index < 150):
                CompanyID, year, company_age, gcp = line[0], line[1], line[2], line[4]
                #print company_name
                company = {\
                    'CompanyID' : CompanyID,\
                    'year' : year,\
                    'company_age' : company_age,\
                    'gcp': int (gcp),\
                }
                companies.append (company)
    return companies

def extract_year_features (companies):
    year_list = list ()
    for company in companies:
        year_list.append (company['year'] * 10)
    tweet_vectorizer = feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer ()
    X = tweet_vectorizer.fit_transform (year_list).toarray ()
    return X


def extract_company_age_features (companies):
    company_age_list = list ()
    for company in companies:
        company_age_list.append (company['company_age'] * 10)
    tweet_vectorizer = feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer ()
    X = tweet_vectorizer.fit_transform (company_age_list).toarray ()
    return X

def extract_all_features (companies):
    return np.concatenate ( (extract_year_features (companies), \
                          extract_company_age_features (companies)), \
                          axis=1)


def generate_target (companies):
    y = [company['gcp'] for company in companies]
    return np.array (y)

companies = parseFile ("sample.csv")
X = extract_all_features (companies)
y = generate_target (companies)

print(X)
print(y)

#Credit to G.Li
```

The print(X) looks like below that are not the real values of the columns.

```
print(X)
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

where as the print (y) looks seemingly alright.

```
print(y)
[0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
```

Does anybody have any idea where I did wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the help! :) didn't figure out how to align like that

Answer (score 0):

I would really urge you to start using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), as you can easily read most data types into a easy-to-navigate 'dataframe'. All the code you need for importing your csv file would be

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.readcsv("sample.csv")
```

You can then easily access the columns you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try panda this evening. Meanwhile, please offer your suggestion if my error is obvious.